# suddenly PossibleAuthenticationFailureError in amqp

Tags: ruby, amqp

I'm using the ruby `amqp` gem. I ran a `AMQP.start` event loop, but 'suddenly`it raised a`PossibleAuthenticationFailureError` during the loop.

```
  AMQP.start(amqp_config) do |connection|
    channel = AMQP::Channel.new connection
    channel.on_error do |channel, channel_close|
      puts "Oops... a channel-level exception: code = #{channel_close.reply_code}, message = #{channel_close.reply_text}"
    end

    my_worker = MyWorker.new
    my_worker.start
  end

[amqp] Detected TCP connection failure
/home/raincole/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/amq-client-0.9.3/lib/amq/client/async/adapters/event_machine.rb:164:in `block in initialize': AMQP broker closed TCP connection before authentication succeeded: this usually means authentication failure due to misconfiguration. Settings are {:host=>"localhost", :port=>5672, :user=>"guest", :pass=>"guest", :vhost=>"/", :timeout=>nil, :logging=>false, :ssl=>false, :broker=>nil, :frame_max=>131072} (AMQP::PossibleAuthenticationFailureError)
```

The weird part is, my worker have received some messages **before** I got `PossibleAuthenticationFailureError`. It seems like that the configuration should be correct(and I checked it over and over again).

Are there other potential reasons for `PossibleAuthenticationFailureError`?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm seeing the same problem.

Answer (score 8):

I recommend a 4 step approach to investigating this issue:

a) Eliminate the obvious - Are your credentials correct and is the user account alive and well (default = 'guest')? Are you connecting to the appropriate vhost (default = '/')?

```
$ rabbitmqctl list_users

Listing users ...
guest   [administrator]
...done.

$ rabbitmqctl list_user_permissions guest

Listing permissions for user "guest" ...
/   .*  .*  .*
<your_vhost>    .*  .*  .*
...done.
```

b) What do the rabbitmq connection logs say?

On a Mac OS installation of rabbitmq (using brew), the logs can be found in /usr/local/var/log/rabbitmq, but your log location could be elsewhere depending on OS and installation preferences.

You may see the following lines in the rabbit@localhost.log file. Not a lot of help...and so proceed to step (c). Otherwise, investigate as per what you see in the log.

```
=INFO REPORT==== 15-Feb-2013::00:42:21 ===
accepting AMQP connection <0.691.0> (127.0.0.1:53108 -> 127.0.0.1:5672)

=WARNING REPORT==== 15-Feb-2013::00:42:21 ===
closing AMQP connection <0.691.0> (127.0.0.1:53108 -> 127.0.0.1:5672):
connection_closed_abruptly
```

c) Is rabbitmq's listener (Erlang client) alive. Default port = 5672. Simplest way to check is to send a garbage message to that port and look for an 'AMQP' response:

```
$ telnet localhost 5672
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
asdasd
AMQP
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

(d) Is the event loop reactor closing prematurely, before the AMQP.connect (or AMQP.start) actions have had a chance to complete authentication?

```
EM.run
  connection = AMQP.connect(:host => 'localhost', :vhost => '/') do
    # your code here
  end
  EM.stop
end
```

With all 'your code' sitting in a callback, the EM.stop runs instantaneously after the AMQP.connect instruction. This gives no time for the connection to be suitably established.

What worked for me here was to add a timer and handle disconnects gracefully.

```
EM.run
  connection = AMQP.connect(:host => 'localhost', :vhost => '/')
    # your code here
  end

  graceful_exit = Proc.new { 
    connection.close { EM.stop }
   }
  EM.add_timer(3, graceful_exit)
end
```

The reason I put the EM.stop block in a Proc is so that I can reuse it for other graceful exits (say, when trapping 'TERM' and 'INT' signals)

Hope this helps.